# I don't know why this is happened and i don't know how to ask this question

Tags: android, node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm using termux app, then i try to install npm packages in the different directory in my phone.

**The first one "/storage/shared/coding"**

```
.../0/Coding $ npm i node-session
npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm WARN deprecated @mapbox/geojsonhint@2.0.1: Please make plans to check GeoJSON in some other way
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../@mapbox/geojsonhint/bin/geojsonhint
npm ERR! dest /storage/emulated/0/Coding/node_modules/.bin/geojsonhint
npm ERR! errno -1
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../@mapbox/geojsonhint/bin/geojsonhint' -> '/storage/emulated/0/Coding/node_modules/.bin/geojsonhint'
npm ERR!  [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, symlink '../@mapbox/geojsonhint/bin/geojsonhint' -> '/storage/emulated/0/Coding/node_modules/.bin/geojsonhint'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -1,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../@mapbox/geojsonhint/bin/geojsonhint',
npm ERR!   dest: '/storage/emulated/0/Coding/node_modules/.bin/geojsonhint'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.npm/_logs/2022-04-25T19_14_38_772Z-debug-0.log
.../0/Coding $  pwd
/storage/emulated/0/Coding
```

**And the second one "/noda"**

```
~/noda $ npm i node-session
npm WARN deprecated nomnom@1.8.1: Package no longer supported. Contact support@npmjs.com for more info.
npm WARN deprecated @mapbox/geojsonhint@2.0.1: Please make plans to check GeoJSON in some other way

added 151 packages, and audited 152 packages in 7s

43 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

17 vulnerabilities (1 moderate, 12 high, 4 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.

Run `npm audit` for details.
~/noda $ pwd
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/noda
```

**Why does node-session can be installed in /noda directory but not in /storage/shared/coding and how can i install it in /storage/shared/coding**

Comment: You're using a Node package that hasn't been updated in about 8 years.  In the Node world this is much greater than infinity.  I'd reevaluate your code first.

Answer (score 0):

NodeJs you installed on Termux doesn't have permission to install dependencies on `/storage/emulated/0/Coding/node_modules/.bin/geojsonhint`.

You can solve it by:

- Changing the directory of the project to somewhere with public permissession.
- Running the command with the administration privilege but on Termux, I think.
- Using nvm to install node js instead of default ways.

This problem comes when you try to install node js with Termux. try not to.

**NVM repository link:** [nvm-sh/nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm).

pay attention:

- You need to check your dependency tree is compatible with the node version you want to install.
- If the project is big be careful because you can break your project easily.

Comment: Thanks sir! Anyway, if i change the directory of the project, i can't use "node-session". Because i think "node-session" is only work on the "/noda" folder or another folder at the same directory.